# JavaScript RegExp: test and exec

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get URLs of all images in multiline text (no matter what it contains).

This is my code:

```
var pattern = /(http:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg|JPG|GIF|PNG|JPEG))/mg;
var testResult = pattern.test(str));
var result = pattern.exec(str);
```

If **str** equals **"http://example.dom.com/-6/x_5eb0916a.jpg"**, **testResult** equals **true** but **result** is **null**. Why? Would you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You have one `)` too much at the end of line 2. Also what is `str`? It's undefined in your code.

Comment: It could be helpful to add a `\/` between your domain and file extension patterns, to prevent subdomains from being parsed otherwise `http://some.png.example.com/home.html` will give you `http://some.png` (I concede it's just a matter of principle ;) ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because of the `g` flag. If you invert the two calls, you'll get different results because the global flag sets [`pattern.lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Properties_2) and starts matching from that index the next time you call `.test`/`.exec`. When inverting the calls, you'd get a non-`null` result for `.exec`, and `false` for `.test`.

With `.lastIndex` and the global flag, in your case it matches the URL for `.test`, and will start looking for more URLs *after* the first URL when you execute `.exec`. There are no more URLs, so you'll get `null`. Note that `lastIndex` is then reset to `0`, so calling `.exec` again would work.

Anyhow, you seem to be looking for `str.match(pattern)` instead, which simply lists all matches:

```
var str = " test http://example.dom.com/-6/x_5eb0916a.jpg"
             + " \nfoo http://example2.com/test.png";

var pattern = /(http:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg|JPG|GIF|PNG|JPEG))/gm;

str.match(pattern);
// ["http://example.dom.com/-6/x_5eb0916a.jpg", "http://example2.com/test.png"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution to this issue is to simply set lastIndex of regex to zero.

```
var pattern = /(http:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg|JPG|GIF|PNG|JPEG))/mg;
var testResult = pattern.test(str));
pattern.lastIndex=0;
var result = pattern.exec(str);
pattern.lastIndex=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this,

```
"http://example.dom.com/-6/x_5eb0916a.jpg".match(pattern)
```

Answer (score 1):

also try returning a function that creates the regex instead of resetting the lastIndex each time.

```js
function getRegex(){
  return /(http:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg|JPG|GIF|PNG|JPEG))/mg;
}

const testResult = getRegex().test(str);
```